# Call a Rally app from my confluence page

Tags: html

I am currently calling and displaying a Rally App inside a Confluence page. The problem is the chart or report is not displaying any data. Its blank, I later realized that its pulling a different report that shares the same name. DefectsbyState is the report im pulling however I get a different report that contains no data. When I view the DefectsbyState report from within Rally I see all the Data I need. Has anyone ever had this problem

Here is a sample of my code :
    {html} 
     
     
     
     
     
     
    function onLoad() { 
    var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource( 
    '**WORKSPACE_OID**', 
    '**PROJECT_OID**', 
    '**PROJECT_SCOPING_UP**', 
    '**PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN**'); 
    rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.destroy(); 
    var reportConfig = {report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.DefectsbyState,
    width : 400, height: 300};
    var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(reportConfig); 
    report.display("reportDiv"); 
    }
    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad); 
     
     
    
 
    {html}